# Gradle sync failed: Could not find method leftShift() for arguments on task ':cdvPrintProps'

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, build.gradle

I'm trying to build an APK from a cordova project using Android Studio 3.4.2.
When I open the android project I have this error:

> Gradle sync failed: Could not find method leftShift() for arguments [build_2k0coljhzjx4l5ohcvglm58rl$_run_closure5@420a76b7] on task ':cdvPrintProps' of type org.gradle.api.DefaultTask.
>               Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (976 ms)

When I open the file where the error is, I see this:

```
task cdvPrintProps << {
    println('cdvCompileSdkVersion=' + cdvCompileSdkVersion)
    println('cdvBuildToolsVersion=' + cdvBuildToolsVersion)
    println('cdvVersionCode=' + cdvVersionCode)
    println('cdvMinSdkVersion=' + cdvMinSdkVersion)
    println('cdvBuildMultipleApks=' + cdvBuildMultipleApks)
    println('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile)
    println('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile)
    println('cdvBuildArch=' + cdvBuildArch)
    println('computedVersionCode=' + android.defaultConfig.versionCode)
    android.productFlavors.each { flavor ->
        println('computed' + flavor.name.capitalize() + 'VersionCode=' + flavor.versionCode)
    }
}
```

I've read that I should change *<<* by *doLast{}*, but if I type:

```
task cdvPrintProps { doLast {
    println('cdvCompileSdkVersion=' + cdvCompileSdkVersion)
    println('cdvBuildToolsVersion=' + cdvBuildToolsVersion)
    println('cdvVersionCode=' + cdvVersionCode)
    println('cdvMinSdkVersion=' + cdvMinSdkVersion)
    println('cdvBuildMultipleApks=' + cdvBuildMultipleApks)
    println('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile)
    println('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile)
    println('cdvBuildArch=' + cdvBuildArch)
    println('computedVersionCode=' + android.defaultConfig.versionCode)
    android.productFlavors.each { flavor ->
        println('computed' + flavor.name.capitalize() + 'VersionCode=' + flavor.versionCode)
    }}}
```

Then I get this other error:

> Gradle sync failed: Cause: org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions.setBootClasspath(Ljava/lang/String;)V
>               Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (1 s 10 ms)

Do you know how can I skip this and have a correct gradle sync?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is not a solution, but I have skipped the errors by changing the gradle version to 3.5.
This can be done in Android Studio by clicking File > Project Structure, and changing the Gradlle Version.

Still, if someone knows another way to actually fix this, please, feel free to share it.

Comment: This also seems to work for me, I had to use gradle 4.1 though.